# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,128) into shape (1,128)

Tags: python, neural-network, shapes, prediction

i'm creating a neural network that predict different type of drugs, and i'm getting an error that i don't understand and i don't find the issue in the code, if anyone can help me and give me an explanation please.

This is the Traceback of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\matte\code\projects\python_projects\simple_drug_classification\rework.py", line 93, in <module>
    model = model_class.model_training()
  File "C:\Users\matte\code\projects\python_projects\simple_drug_classification\rework.py", line 50, in model_training
    model.fit(
  File "C:\Users\matte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\matte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1997, in __array__
    values = self._values
  File "C:\Users\matte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1001, in _values
    return ensure_wrapped_if_datetimelike(self.values)
  File "C:\Users\matte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 11360, in values
    return self._mgr.as_array()
  File "C:\Users\matte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1732, in as_array
    arr = self._interleave(dtype=dtype, na_value=na_value)
  File "C:\Users\matte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1794, in _interleave
    result[rl.indexer] = arr
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,128) into shape (1,128)
```

This is the part of the code where i create the neural network model:

```
class Model:
    def __init__(self, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test):
        self.X_train = X_train
        self.X_test = X_test
        self.y_train = y_train
        self.y_test = y_test

        self.N_HIDDEN_LAYERS = 128
        self.NB_CLASSES = 5


    def model_architecture(self):
        model = keras.models.Sequential()

        model.add(keras.layers.Dense(
            self.N_HIDDEN_LAYERS, input_shape=(6,), activation="relu"
        ))

        model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
        
        model.add(keras.layers.Dense(
            self.N_HIDDEN_LAYERS, activation="relu"
        ))

        model.add(keras.layers.Dense(
            self.NB_CLASSES, activation="softmax"
        ))

        model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
        return model

    
    def model_training(self):
        model = self.model_architecture()

        BATCH_SIZE = 32
        EPOCHS = 10
        VERBOSE = 1
        VALIDATION_SPLIT = 0.2

        model.fit(
            self.X_train,
            self.y_train,
            batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
            epochs=EPOCHS,
            verbose=VERBOSE,
            validation_split=VALIDATION_SPLIT
        )

        model.evaluate(self.X_test, self.y_test)
        model.save("model")
```

And this is the part of the code where i preprocess the data:

```
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

numerical_data = data[["Age", "Na_to_K"]]
categorical_data = data[["Sex", "Drug"]]
text_data = data[["BP", "Cholesterol"]]

# Label encode categorical data
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
for column in categorical_data.columns:
    categorical_data[column] = label_encoder.fit_transform(categorical_data[column])

# TF-IDF vectorization for text data
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
for column in text_data.columns:
    text_data[column] = vectorizer.fit_transform(text_data[column]).toarray()

# Standard scaling for numerical data
scaler = StandardScaler()
numerical_data = scaler.fit_transform(numerical_data)

# Merge all data together
merged_data = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(numerical_data), categorical_data, pd.DataFrame(text_data)], axis=1)

# Split data into training and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(merged_data, data["Drug"], test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

print("X_train shape: ", X_train.shape, " y_train shape: ", y_train.shape)
print("X_test shape: ", X_test.shape, " y_test shape: ", y_test.shape)

model_class = Model(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)
model = model_class.model_training()
```

The shapes of X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test are these:

```
X_train shape:  (160, 6)  y_train shape:  (160,)
X_test shape:  (40, 6)  y_test shape:  (40,)
```

And final, the data that i have in **data.csv** looks like this:

```
Age,Sex,BP,Cholesterol,Na_to_K,Drug
23,F,HIGH,HIGH,25.355,DrugY
```

I've tried to convert y_train and y_test in arrays, reshape these in (-1, 1) and then encode with OneHotencoding, but i still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue lies in the `preprocessing` step. you're using the `LabelEncoder` to encode the "Drug" column, which is your `output` label. However, LabelEncoder does not support one-hot encoding, which is necessary for `multi-class` classification problems like yours.

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
#...

# One-hot encode output labels
onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
y_train_encoded = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(y_train.values.reshape(-1, 1))
y_test_encoded = onehot_encoder.transform(y_test.values.reshape(-1, 1))

# ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but i tried this on my code and the error is still the same.

Comment: okay i will edit this, but you got the point that you cannot use `Label Encoder` for Output in  `Multi-Class` classification problem.

Comment: Yes i understood it, i removed the data "Drug" from the categorical_data, where then i use label encoder on it.